# How to make a PreferenceFragment work with the MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-preferences

In my MainActivity onCreate method, I have

```
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment())
    .commit();
```

What this does is adding the `PreferenceFragment` to my app's content `ViewGroup` but it makes also the MainActivity's content inaccessible (the buttons can no longer be clicked).

My question is: is there a way to make a `PreferenceFragment` work with the MainActivity so that both `Activity` and `Fragment` are accessible?

Thanks Jon

Comment: post your preferenceFargment and mainActivity code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inflate your `Fragment` into a container view.

To do this, add a `ViewGroup` to your Activitie's layout file, for example:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And use this in your Activity:

```
getFragmentManager()
      .beginTransaction()
      .add(R.id.container, new MyPreferenceFragment())
      .commit();
```

Now you can just show the `Fragment` in the given container without overwriting the layout of the MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

```
getFragmentManager()
      .beginTransaction()
      .add(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment())
      .commit();
```

That's it!